# How to construct xpath for links using 'contains text'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I need to construct Xpath for links based on contains text. I have written below code to get it. However if I have three links like 'Entity', 'Entity Type' and 'Entity Group', and if I click on 'Entity', it generates xpath like `//a[contains(text(),"Entity")]`

However when Selenium WebDriver identifies the element, it sees three objects which contains text with 'Entity'. For this, Selenium IDE records 'Entity' link with an index. How can I modify below code to check that condition and add indexes? Please help.

```
function getXPath(element) {
    if(element.tagName == 'A'){
    if($(element).find("IMG").length>0 || $(element).find("I").length>0 || $(element).find("SPAN").length>0 || $(element).find("DIV").length>0){
    }else{
    return '//a[contains(text(),"'+ element.innerHTML.trim() +'")]';    
    }
    }

    if(element.tagName == 'IMG' || element.tagName == 'I'){
    if((typeof element.alt !== 'undefined') && element.alt!='')
    return '//img[alt="'+ element.alt +'"]';
    }

    if (element.id!=='')
        return '//*[@id="'+ element.id +'"]';
    if (element===document.body)
        return element.tagName;
    var ix= 0;
    var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {
        var sibling= siblings[i];
        if (sibling===element)
            return getXPath(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';
        if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)
            ix++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format the question better - what's the issue here? What is this code? What is it meant to be doing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure what your script is trying to accomplish, but it sounds like the simplest solution is to match the link text *exactly* since partial matches give you conflicts, instead of writing extra code to handle conflicts. So, rewrite the xpath, and remove .trim() if you need the whitespace for an exact text match:

```
return '//a[text()="'+ element.innerHTML +'"]';
```

If exact text matches won't work for your use case, can you give more detail of what your script is trying to accomplish?

I also noticed you're missing the @ for this xpath, in case this is also giving you errors when you're testing:

```
 return '//img[@alt="'+ element.alt +'"]';
```